# How to update text Labels in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Every time I click the button to get the weather (I used Json to get info from a website), the previous text remains and new text is printed under it, but I want the old text to be updated. How can I do that? Please help.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")
root.geometry("600x400")

def RealWeather():

    try:
        api_request = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=c2fc19de6fcd6869c4a9e167ee0f2eb7&q=" + city.get())
        api = json.loads(api_request.content)
        location = api['name'] + ", " + api['sys']['country']
        temp = int(api['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
        ws = api['wind']['speed']
        status = api['weather'][0]['main']

        Labelloc = Label(root, text="Location",background='#5182cf').grid(row=2,column=0)
        Label_loc = Label(root, text=location ,background='#5182cf').grid(row=2, column=1)

        Labeltemp = Label(root, text="Temperature",background='#5182cf').grid(row=3,column=0)
        Label_temp = Label(root, text=temp,background='#5182cf').grid(row=3,column=1)

        Labelws = Label(root, text="Wind Speed",background='#5182cf').grid(row=4,column=0)
        Label_ws = Label(root, text=ws,background='#5182cf').grid(row=4,column=1)

        Labelstatus = Label(root, text="Status",background='#5182cf').grid(row=5,column=0)
        Label_status = Label(root, text=status,background='#5182cf').grid(row=5,column=1)


    except Exception as e:
        api = "Error..."

    EmptyLabel = Label(root, text="", background='#5182cf').grid(row=1, column=0)


butn = Button(root, text="Search", command=RealWeather).grid(row=0, column=3)
Label1 = Label(root, text="Enter City: ").grid(row=0,column=0)
city = Entry(root)
city.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can change the text of an existing `Label` with something like `my_label.config(text='new text')`. Your code is creating new `Label`s every time the function is called instead of updating existing instances — which would be a better way to do things.

Comment: @martineau Hey I'm still new, can you please tell me how?

Comment: I considered do that, but am unable to run the code currently in your question due to the dependencies on unrelated stuff. If you [edit] it and provide a [mre] without all the extraneous stuff, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @martineau, Thanks a lot it's really kind! I will edit the post so you can see all the code

Comment: All your labels are `None` and hence you cant edit it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to fix your problems by using the universal widget `config()` method I mentioned in my comment:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")
root.geometry("600x400")


def create_labels():
    global Label_loc, Label_temp, Label_ws, Label_status

    Label(root, text="Location",background='#5182cf').grid(row=2,column=0)
    Label_loc = Label(root, background='#5182cf')
    Label_loc.grid(row=2, column=1)

    Label(root, text="Temperature",background='#5182cf').grid(row=3,column=0)
    Label_temp = Label(root, background='#5182cf')
    Label_temp.grid(row=3,column=1)

    Labelws = Label(root, text="Wind Speed", background='#5182cf').grid(row=4,column=0)
    Label_ws = Label(root, background='#5182cf')
    Label_ws.grid(row=4,column=1)

    Labelstatus = Label(root, text="Status", background='#5182cf').grid(row=5,column=0)
    Label_status = Label(root, background='#5182cf')
    Label_status.grid(row=5,column=1)


def RealWeather():
    # Not strickly necessary, but good documentation.
    global Label_loc, Label_temp, Label_ws, Label_status

    try:
        api_request = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=c2fc19de6fcd6869c4a9e167ee0f2eb7&q=" + city.get())
        api = json.loads(api_request.content)
        location = api['name'] + ", " + api['sys']['country']
        temp = int(api['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
        ws = api['wind']['speed']
        status = api['weather'][0]['main']

        Label_loc.config(text=location)
        Label_temp.config(text=temp)
        Label_ws.config(text=ws)
        Label_status.config(text=status)

    except Exception as e:
        print('error occurred:', e)


create_labels()
butn = Button(root, text="Search", command=RealWeather)
butn.grid(row=0, column=3)
Label1 = Label(root, text="Enter City: ")
Label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
city = Entry(root)
city.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

P.S. I also *strongly* suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thank you very much! have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would proceed with your answer. First create the labels outside the function and use `grid()` on separate lines, so they are not `None`.

```
Labelloc = Label(root, text="Location",background='#5182cf')
Label_loc = Label(root)

Labeltemp = Label(root, text="Temperature",background='#5182cf')
Label_temp = Label(root)

Labelws = Label(root, text="Wind Speed",background='#5182cf')
Label_ws = Label(root)

Labelstatus = Label(root, text="Status",background='#5182cf')
Label_status = Label(root)
```

Now inside the function, you have to call the `config()` method to update the label each time the function is run:

```
Labelloc.grid(row=2,column=0) #grid it when the func is ran
Label_loc.config(text=location,background='#5182cf')
Label_loc.grid(row=2, column=1) #grid it when the func is ran

Labeltemp.grid(row=3,column=0) #grid it when the func is ran
Label_temp.config(background='#5182cf')
Label_temp.grid(row=3,column=1) #grid it when the func is ran

Labelws.grid(row=4,column=0) #grid it when the func is ran
Label_ws.config(text=ws,background='#5182cf')
Label_ws.grid(row=4,column=1) #grid it when the func is ran

Labelstatus.grid(row=5,column=0)
Label_status.config(text=status,background='#5182cf')
Label_status.grid(row=5,column=1)
```

So final code:

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")
root.geometry("600x400")

def RealWeather():

    try:
        api_request = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=c2fc19de6fcd6869c4a9e167ee0f2eb7&q=" + city.get())
        api = json.loads(api_request.content)
        location = api['name'] + ", " + api['sys']['country']
        temp = int(api['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
        ws = api['wind']['speed']
        status = api['weather'][0]['main']

        Labelloc.grid(row=2,column=0)
        Label_loc.config(text=location,background='#5182cf')
        Label_loc.grid(row=2, column=1)

        Labeltemp.grid(row=3,column=0)
        Label_temp.config(background='#5182cf')
        Label_temp.grid(row=3,column=1)

        Labelws.grid(row=4,column=0)
        Label_ws.config(text=ws,background='#5182cf')
        Label_ws.grid(row=4,column=1)

        Labelstatus.grid(row=5,column=0)
        Label_status.config(text=status,background='#5182cf')
        Label_status.grid(row=5,column=1)

    except Exception as e:
        api = "Error..."

    EmptyLabel = Label(root, text="", background='#5182cf').grid(row=1, column=0)

butn = Button(root, text="Search", command=RealWeather).grid(row=0, column=3)
Label1 = Label(root, text="Enter City: ").grid(row=0,column=0)
city = Entry(root)
city.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)

Labelloc = Label(root, text="Location",background='#5182cf')
Label_loc = Label(root)

Labeltemp = Label(root, text="Temperature",background='#5182cf')
Label_temp = Label(root)

Labelws = Label(root, text="Wind Speed",background='#5182cf')
Label_ws = Label(root)

Labelstatus = Label(root, text="Status",background='#5182cf')
Label_status = Label(root)

root.mainloop()
```

If you wish to use `threading` then it would be like:

```
# all imports
import threading

.... #same all code 
butn = Button(root, text="Search", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=RealWeather).start())
btn.grid(row=0, column=3)
.... #same all code
```

Why use threading? It wont freeze the GUI while python fetches data from api.
**Though using threading with `tkinter` is not a very good option, there are some downsides to it, but for this simple example, it might be fine to work with it.**

Comment: Thank you I'm going to consider using threading. Thanks!

Comment: Cool: Generally speaking `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading, so I have doubts about that part of your answer…

Comment: Cool: My understanding is that only one thread in a multithreaded script should access the GUI to prevent concurreny problems (which is what I meant about it not supporting multithreading). Perhaps you're getting away with breaking that rule because the sample code in this case is so simple.

Comment: @martineau Yea thats correct too, this is a simple case, ill mention it in the question.